# mobile performance using mapbox

Tags: react-native, mapbox, react-redux, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to use Mapbox ( https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl ) with React-Native, React Redux and Flux Navigation.

I have structured my application in a modular where I have a single module search and map. It is structured like this:

```
/modules
   /search
       /containers
           SearchResults.js
   /map
      /containers
           Map.js
```

In SearchResults.js I get 10 results which are displayed with an image and a text. The results are stored in my redux store. 
I have 2 buttons in Map.js and SearchResults.js which enable the navigation between the 2 containers (forward and backwards via Flux navigation Action.Map() and Action.SearchResults() ).

In Map.js I am updating the map state to receive longitude and latitude from the searchResult store. The problem I am facing right now is, that there are massive performance issues if I switch between SearchResults and Map forwards and backwards. This happens because the map is always being rerendered.

I tried to find a workaround with using the react lifecycle methods, but that didn't help. I think this is useless because I navigate between 2 modules.

What is the best way to prevent Map.js from rerendering all the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what `type` keyword is made for in your `Scene` definition. According to [documentation](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API_CONFIGURATION.md%22documentation%22) of react-native-router-flux:

> Scene type
>
> Defines how the new screen is added to the navigator stack. One of
>   push, jump, replace, reset. If parent container is tabbar (tabs=true),
>   jump will be automatically set.

And if we look at react native official [Navigator documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html) we learn that jumping between scenes allows us to change screen without unmounting.

By default react-native-router-flux uses push which unmounts your scenes.

I did not try it by myself but I think it should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I had this issue when Map.js was not a part of the tabbar container, After moving it to the tabbar, it stopped rerendering. Thanks a lot! :)